# Bootstrap modal passing data

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using Bootstrap2.3.2,

```
function showmodal(arg1){$('#myModal').modal({keyboard:true,backdrop:'static'});
$('#myModal').on('hidden',function(){
    alert(arg1);
});}

function function1 {showmodal("one");}

function function2 {showmodal("two");}
```

When I call the `function1()`, modal will be open and close this modal "one" alert message will be coming. After i am going to call `function2()`,modal will be open and close this modal "one" is coming first alert and "two" is coming second alert. the problem is both alert will coming in the function2.I need to remove the first alert in second function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the function argument as data in the element.

Then you need to move out the event listener, or you will bind multiple events to the same modal:

```
function showmodal(arg1) {
  $('#myModal').data('arg', arg1).modal({
    keyboard:true,
    backdrop:'static'
  });
}

$('#myModal').on('hidden',function(){
  alert($(this).data('arg'));
});

function function1 {showmodal("one");}

function function2 {showmodal("two");}
```

Alternatively, unbind the event listener before binding a new one:

```
function showmodal(arg1){$('#myModal').modal({keyboard:true,backdrop:'static'});
$('#myModal').off('hidden').on('hidden',function(){
    alert(arg1);
});}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a neat function named [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) which allows binding an event handler that will be called at most once per element per event:

```
function showmodal(arg1) {
    $('#myModal').modal({keyboard:true,backdrop:'static'});
    $('#myModal').one('hidden', function () {
        alert(arg1);
    });
}
```

I've reformatted the code but the only functional change in the code above relative to the code in the original question is replacing the call to `on` by a call to `one`. By using `one`, there's no need to unbind the event handler.